# Django - ImportError: No module named city

Tags: python, django, linux, importerror

Django keeps telling me this, even after recoding everything, and I cannot seem to find help on Google. Project folder is as follows:

```
$ tree
.
|-- project
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- settings.py
|   |-- settings.py~
|   |-- settings.pyc
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- urls.pyc
|   |-- wsgi.py
|   `-- wsgi.pyc
|-- city
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- models.pyc
|   |-- tests.py
|   `-- views.py
|-- course
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- models.pyc
|   |-- tests.py
|   `-- views.py
|-- manage.py
|-- perk
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- models.pyc
|   |-- static
|   |-- tests.py
|   `-- views.py
|-- preuniversity
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- models.py~
|   |-- models.pyc
|   |-- tests.py
|   `-- views.py
`-- user
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- __init__.pyc
    |-- models.py
    |-- models.py~
    |-- models.pyc
    |-- tests.py
    `-- views.py
```

The structure has not been changed, neither did I modify anything except for models.py, which is:

```
$ cat city/models.py
from django.db import models

class State(models.Model):
    acronym = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State)
```

I'm just following Django tutorial, no more and no less, and there is no solution. I used startapp on every app (and didn't just copy&paste from another) and the app names are there in settings.py.

If I remove every reference to city (foreign keys, imports and remove from installed_apps) it complains about the next app (course).

Comment: Your `city` is most likely not in the path. Can you show your `manage.py` file ? Alternatively, move `city` into `project` folder (provided `projects/` is in the path)

Comment: In which module do you import the city/models.py..Is it in your views

Comment: @karthikr I'm not sure if it helps, manage.py is the default one, but anyway: http://pastebin.com/P6pakAB7

Comment: @user1050619 I didn't really understand your comment...

Comment: Did you say you removed instance to `city` from installed apps ?

Comment: At which point do you get this error?.."No module named city" should be displayed when you try to import the "city" in another module?

Comment: @karthikr I mean I commented foreign keys that relate to this app (e.g. user's city) AND commented in installed_apps.

Comment: @user1050619 when I do "manage.py validate" or "manage.py syncdb"

Comment: Im sure the import is failing when the "city" module is imported in some other module..place provide that piece of code

Comment: There is, "user" model http://pastebin.com/g66ZguLa

Comment: Where is you USER app? I assume its one of the "app"...try "from city.models import *" of try "from projectname.city.models import *"

Comment: @user1050619 user app is in "user" folder... "from city.models import *" didn't do the trick, now it says `NameError: name 'City' is not defined`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32776/discussion-between-user1050619-and-ranisalt)

Comment: @user1050619 I'm there

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using django 1.4 or later because of what is in your project folder.

Did you create the top-level directory with `django-admin.py startproject`?  I don't see the `__init__.py` file at the top level, although the `project` directory with `settings.py` and `urls.py` is there.  Create an empty file called `__init__.py` at the top level (sibling of `manage.py`) and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes, I did, and no, it didn't change anything.

Comment: Please show your settings.py.  Also, are you running django with the development server (runserver) or with a web server like apache?

Comment: Not needed, really. I managed to fix it and will answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

Put your city (files which you want to import) in root dir of main application.
If IDE(PyCharm for an example) wont worry about import this module - than the problem was in paths.

I've smashed with this problem at once. And the problem paths were.

Comment: I do not use IDE, I'm working only with terminal and gedit. City dir is already on root dir (the dir with manage.py?)

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to fix the errors. Maybe I forgot some important info on the question but here is the explanation:

I downloaded PyDev for Eclipse and rebuilt the project from scratch. So, when I was writing the imports, Eclipse complained it was not right. Well, I went back to Django tutorial and there is `import city`, so I was right. I accepted the suggestion from Eclipse and it changed to `from city.models import City` and it went ok. So I tested with the old project and changed every import, and it validated and synced with no errors.

Now I'm very confused, how could Django documentation be wrong? Or is this Python-version or distro peculiarity? Well, nevermind, it is now working. Thanks everybody :P